# LEFT JOIN include data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application which handles school vacation. Unfortunately there are three kinds of different school vacations: Country wide, Federal State wide and City wide vacations. I store all the information in a table `days`, a table `vacation_periods` and a connection table `slots`:

```
days {
    id:integer
    date_value:date
}
slots {
    id:integer
    day_id:integer
    vacation_period_id:integer
}
vacation_periods {
    id:integer
    starts_on:date
    ends_on:date
    name:string
    country_id:integer
    federal_state_id:integer
    city_id:integer
}
```

I want to select all `days` within a specific time frame. Let's say Jan 1st of 2017 to Jan 31st of 2017. I can get those `days` with:

```
SELECT * FROM days WHERE date_value >= '2017-01-01' AND 
                         date_value <= '2017-01-31';
```

But for my vacation calendar I don't just need the `days` but also the information which `vacation_periods` are within. Assuming I search for all `vacation_periods` which are in that time frame and which have

```
country_id == 1 or federal_state_id == 5 or city_id == 30
```

I've read about JOINS and LEFT JOINS which seem to be the solution to the problem. But I can't get everything together.

Is it possible to send one SQL request which returns all `days` within the requested time frame and the additional information if a `vacation_period` that fits the `country_id == 1 or federal_state_id == 5 or city_id == 30` rule is connected via `slots` to each `day`. Including the name of that `vacation_period`?

If one request is not possible: Which is the quickest way to solve this within the database? How many requests? What kind of requests?

If possible I'd like to get a result in some kind of this form:

```
- date_value: "2017-01-01"
- date_value: "2017-01-02"
- date_value: "2017-01-03"
  * vacation_period.id: 15
  * vacation_period.name: "foobar"
- date_value: "2017-01-04"
  * vacation_period.id: 15
  * vacation_period.name: "foobar"
- date_value: "2017-01-05"
  * vacation_period.id: 15
  * vacation_period.name: "foobar"
- date_value: "2017-01-06"
- date_value: "2017-01-07"
...
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you are looking for.

Comment: What is the purpose of `slots`?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus No purpose. I thought it’s the best solution. I’m open for other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The following query might give you the answer you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM days WHERE date_value >= '2017-01-01' AND date_value <='2017-01-31'

INNER JOIN slots ON days.id = slots.day_id

INNER JOIN vacation_periods ON vacation_periods.id = slots.vacation_period_id
```

Comment: You might want to replace the first [INNER JOIN] for a [LEFT OUTER JOIN] if you want all days to be displayed. Just keep the rest of the query as is.

Comment: Can I use this to only JOIN the vacation_periods which have country_id == 1 or federal_state_id == 5 or city_id == 30? How?

Comment: Try the following query then. It uses subqueries to filter the table. It is getting a little bit complex and I can't try it so it's not guaranteed to work.


SELECT * FROM days WHERE date_value >= '2017-01-01' AND date_value <='2017-01-31'
LEFT OUTER JOIN slots ON days.id = slots.day_id
INNER JOIN (select * from vacation_periods where country_id = 1 OR federal_state_id = 5 OR city_id = 30) as filtered_vacation_periods ON filtered_vacation_periods.id = slots.vacation_period_id

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get an unformatted version of what you want (that could be processed into a hierarchical output) with

```
CREATE TYPE vacation_authority AS ENUM
  ('COUNTY', 'FED-STATE', 'CITY');
/* not necessary, but cleans up the vacation_period table */
```

change to let `vacation_period` have only one id, and a new field `authority` of type `vacation_authority`. You can now make a primary key out of either the id field or (id, authority), depending on how the vacation data comes into the system.

```
SELECT date_value, vp.name, vp.id /* is the ID meaningful or arbitrary? */
FROM dates LEFT JOIN vacation_periods vp
WHERE date_value BETWEEN vp.starts_on AND vp.ends_on; -- inclusive range
```

Now if there are multiple holidays spanning a given date, this will be multiple records in the output. It's not clear what you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers was able to solve my problem but they let me to the solution so I'm grateful for them. Here's the solution:

```
SELECT days.date_value, slots.period_id, vacation_periods.name FROM days 
LEFT OUTER JOIN slots ON (days.id = slots.day_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vacation_periods ON (slots.period_id = vacation_periods.id) 
WHERE days.date_value >= '2017-01-05' 
AND days.date_value <='2017-01-15' 
AND (vacation_periods.id IS NULL 
OR vacation_periods.country_id = 1 
OR vacation_periods.federal_state_id = 5) 
ORDER BY days.date_value;
```

[image: Screenshot of the SQL Query output.]